# XSLT to match list of attributes passed using Java

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to pass a list of attribute values using java and want to check if it exists in attributes of specific nodes. Now I need to write an xslt to achieve the following, please provide some guidance.

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<mtxml> 
<Nav>
<DimVal Name="G" Id="10000" Flags="0" dim="10000" DdmName="Gender" >
    <Property Key="A">10047</Property>
    <Property Key="B">10048</Property>
    <Property Key="C">10049</Property>
    <Property Key="D">2082</Property>
    <Property Key="G">22332</Property>
    <Property Key="H">1121</Property>
    <Property Key="I">2223</Property>
</DimVal>
<DimVal Name="A" Id="11000" Flags="0" dim="11000" DdmName="Address" >
    <Property Key="A">10047</Property>
    <Property Key="B">10048</Property>
    <Property Key="D">2082</Property>
    <Property Key="E">23343</Property>
    <Property Key="F">3323</Property>
    <Property Key="G">22332</Property>
    <Property Key="H">1121</Property>
    <Property Key="I">2223</Property>
</DimVal>
<DimVal Name="R" Id="11001" Flags="0" dim="11001" DdmName="Zip" >
    <Property Key="A">10047</Property>
    <Property Key="B">10048</Property>
    <Property Key="C">44532</Property>
    <Property Key="D">2082</Property>
    <Property Key="E">23343</Property>
    <Property Key="F">3323</Property>
    <Property Key="G">22332</Property>
    <Property Key="H">1121</Property>
    <Property Key="I">2223</Property>
</DimVal>
</Nav>
<Nav>
<DimVal Name="GA" Id="90000" Flags="0" dim="90000" DdmName="Age" >
    <Property Key="A">10047</Property>
    <Property Key="D">2082</Property>
    <Property Key="G">22332</Property>
    <Property Key="H">1121</Property>
    <Property Key="I">2223</Property>
</DimVal>
<DimVal Name="AL" Id="91000" Flags="0" dim="91000" DdmName="Route" >
    <Property Key="A">10047</Property>
    <Property Key="B">10048</Property>
    <Property Key="D">2082</Property>
    <Property Key="E">23343</Property>
    <Property Key="F">3323</Property>
    <Property Key="G">22332</Property>
    <Property Key="H">1121</Property>
    <Property Key="I">2223</Property>
</DimVal>
<DimVal Name="RW" Id="91001" Flags="0" dim="91001" DdmName="Postal Code" >
    <Property Key="A">10047</Property>
    <Property Key="B">10048</Property>
    <Property Key="C">44532</Property>
    <Property Key="D">2082</Property>
    <Property Key="F">3323</Property>
    <Property Key="G">22332</Property>
    <Property Key="H">1121</Property>
</DimVal>
</Nav>
</mtxml>
```

I would be setting the parameters using the following, where parameterValue is Array/ArrayList

```
<!-- language: lang-java-->
xsltTransformer.setParameter(parameterName, parameterValue);
```

Now if I pass {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I'} the I would be expecting the xslt output as following :

```
 <!-- language: lang-xml -->

<DimVal Name="G" Id="10000" Flags="0" dim="10000" DdmName="Gender">
    <Property Key="E" />
    <Property Key="F" />
</DimVal>
<DimVal Name="A" Id="11000" Flags="0" dim="11000" DdmName="Address">
    <Property Key="C" />
</DimVal>
<DimVal Name="GA" Id="90000" Flags="0" dim="90000" DdmName="Age" >
    <Property Key="B" />
    <Property Key="C" />
    <Property Key="E" />
    <Property Key="F" />
</DimVal>
<DimVal Name="AL" Id="91000" Flags="0" dim="91000" DdmName="Route" >
    <Property Key="C" />
</DimVal>
 <DimVal Name="RW" Id="91001" Flags="0" dim="91001" DdmName="Postal Code" >
    <Property Key="E" />
    <Property Key="I" />
</DimVal>
```

I did not incorporate any xslt (I couldn't work it out) , 1st XML is the input xml and the 2nd is the expected output. Parameter values passed are the list of attribute values for 'Key' attribute for the 'Property' element.

Comment: To read parameters inside the XLST you just need to define global parameters using a top-level `<xsl:param name="parameterName" />`. Is your `parameterValue` the string `"{'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I'}"`? It's not clear if you included a source document. Are both documents expected results? How are the letters sent in the parameterValue related to the result XML?

Comment: I did not incorporate any xslt, 1st XML is the input xml and the 2nd is the expected output. Parameter values passed are the list of attribute values for 'Key' attribute for the 'Property' element.

Comment: When you did not incorporate any XSLT, then how do you hope to get any output from the `xsltTransformer`?

Comment: The output is manually generated, I could not think of a way to write the XSLT to generate the output. It would be nice to know if one such xslt can be written, if yes can somebody provide me some directions

Comment: It **is** possible to generate a XML using XSLT but it's necessary to know the logic behind the transformation. E.g.: why does dimval `G` in the result have those two properties `E` and `F`? Why does dimval `A` only contain property`C`? What role does your input parameter value `{'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I'}` have in that result? If the input is `{'A','F'}` for example, what would change in the output. That's what's missing in this question.

Comment: Every DimVal should at least have 9 child element 'Property' with attribute 'Key' as one of the following 'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I' respectively, if any one of the DimVal have a missing property/@key among given set {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I'} , the missing should be there in the output. Eg: As `<DimVal Name="R" Id="11001" Flags="0" dim="11001" DdmName="Zip" >` has all the attributes its not there in the output, every other DimVal is there as they have one or the other missing.

Comment: If the input is {'A','F'}  then output should be `<DimVal Name="G" Id="10000" Flags="0" dim="10000" DdmName="Gender">
    <Property Key="F" />
</DimVal>
<DimVal Name="GA" Id="90000" Flags="0" dim="90000" DdmName="Age" >
    <Property Key="F" />
</DimVal>` because these two DimVals have 'F' missing, and 'A' is present in all DimVal

Comment: Please indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. Also please do not post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k, XSLT 1.0 would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, I have made an adjustment to the format of the passed parameter. If this is not possible, you will need to add a named template (or use a EXSLT function, if your processor supports it) in order to tokenize the parameter. Or consider having this list in a separate XML document.

**XSLT 1.0 (+ EXSLT node-set() function)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="required-keys">
    <key>A</key>
    <key>B</key>
    <key>C</key>
    <key>D</key>
    <key>E</key>
    <key>F</key>
    <key>G</key>
    <key>H</key>
    <key>I</key>
</xsl:param>

<xsl:variable name="required-keys-set" select="exsl:node-set($required-keys)" />
<xsl:variable name="required-count" select="count($required-keys-set/key)" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<output>
    <xsl:for-each select="mtxml/Nav/DimVal[not(count(Property/@Key[.=$required-keys-set/key])=$required-count)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:variable name="my-keys" select="Property/@Key"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$required-keys-set/key[not(.=$my-keys)]">
                <Property Key="{.}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
</output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your input (minus the illegal comment at the top of the document), the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <DimVal Name="G" Id="10000" Flags="0" dim="10000" DdmName="Gender">
      <Property Key="E"/>
      <Property Key="F"/>
   </DimVal>
   <DimVal Name="A" Id="11000" Flags="0" dim="11000" DdmName="Address">
      <Property Key="C"/>
   </DimVal>
   <DimVal Name="GA" Id="90000" Flags="0" dim="90000" DdmName="Age">
      <Property Key="B"/>
      <Property Key="C"/>
      <Property Key="E"/>
      <Property Key="F"/>
   </DimVal>
   <DimVal Name="AL" Id="91000" Flags="0" dim="91000" DdmName="Route">
      <Property Key="C"/>
   </DimVal>
   <DimVal Name="RW" Id="91001" Flags="0" dim="91001" DdmName="Postal Code">
      <Property Key="E"/>
      <Property Key="I"/>
   </DimVal>
</output>
```

Note the added root element missing from your required output.

Changing the passed parameter to:

```
<key>A</key>
<key>F</key>
```

will produce the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <DimVal Name="G" Id="10000" Flags="0" dim="10000" DdmName="Gender">
      <Property Key="F"/>
   </DimVal>
   <DimVal Name="GA" Id="90000" Flags="0" dim="90000" DdmName="Age">
      <Property Key="F"/>
   </DimVal>
</output>
```